# How to represent this SQL query in LINQ to entities?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I'm kind of new to LINQ and I'm trying to represent the following query in LINQ to Entities:

```
Select * from Cotations CT1 
where CT1.CotationID = iCot_ID and 
      Revision = 
          (select max(revision) 
          from Cotations CT2 
          where CT1.CotationID = CT2.Cotation)
```

where `iCot_ID` is an external parameter, and `Cotations` is my entity set.

Better yet, how can I represent this as an association between two entities?

If I have the following entities:

MasterLog:

--cotationID

Cotation:

--Cotationid

--Revision key,

and for each `MasterLog` I want to have an association with `Cotation` based only on `CotationID` where `Revision` is max for that `cotation` (as in above query)

Thanks.

Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

I think you have overcomplicated your query.  The below should do it.

```
int iCot_ID  = 0;

var query = (
  from c in context.Coalation
   .Where(x=>x.Cotationid == iCot_ID)
   .OrderByDesc(x=>x.Revision)
 )
.FirstOrDefault();
```

---

I don't quite understand the second half of your question.  Please take some time and further explain what you would like to do with `MasterLog`.

Here is a guess:

```
var cQuery = (
           from c in context.Coalation
                  group c by g.Revision into g
                  orderby g.Revision descending
           select g.First()
);

var mQuery = (
           from m in MasterLog
           join c in cQuery 
               on m.cotationID equals c.Cotationid
           where 
              m.Cotationid==iCot_ID 
           select new {
                MasterLog = m,
                Cotation = c
            }

);
```